# Filter Realm Result by Integer

Tags: java, android, realm, contains

There are two methods to filter realmResult in java by "string"

```
RealmResults  data = realm.where(RasifalDTO.class).contains(keyString,valueString);
```

But what i want to do is filter the Result with Respect to integer so i tried:

```
RealmResults  data = realm.where(RasifalDTO.class).contains(keyString,vauleInt+"");
```

But i get  :

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field 'rasifalType': type mismatch. Was INTEGER, expected [STRING]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to filter the result by an attribute of the Realm Object which happens to be an integer. Then `equalTo(String key,int  value)` is the way to go (**Do not get confused with using** `contains(key string,value string)` **like i was** ).

```
RealmResult data = realm.where(RasifalDTO.class).equalTo(keyString,valueInt).findAll();
```

Comment: why don't you just use equalTo

Comment: Why did i not see those methods ? thanks so much @TimCastelijns

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12870366)

Comment: @LaxmanBhattarai Explain your answer clearly to understand others. It will makes helpful to someone who looks your answer on future.

Comment: @SVMRAJESH is it ok for now ?

Comment: @LaxmanBhattarai Now you answer looks great. Clear explanation can give more reputation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
RealmResults  data = realm.where(RasifalDTO.class).contains(keyString,String.valueOf(vauleInt));
```

Comment: Still did not work because the keyString  in RasifalDTO.class  is an int